# How to extract the GPS data of the markers that I added in my shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gps, markers

I was wondering, is it possible to extract the GPS coordinates of the red markers that I added in a shapefile in QGIS?

[image]

Comment: Hey, as a first step you can use the field editor to add new fields for the latitude and longitude coordinates. Use    $x    and    $y    for longitude and latitude, respectively. (I am assuming the red markers are features of a point layer)

Comment: But I don't want to add new fields, I want to export the marker's coordinates I put along a line into a csv file because later I need to match them with other data in R and in Python

Comment: The red markers are not features of a point layer, they were made under "Symbology" of a shapefile containing railway lines

Comment: Ah OK that was not clear to me from your question, you might need to reformulate the question a bit so the right person will see and answer it :)

Answer (score 3):

No, those points were added a markers to a line feature.  In QGIS you can create points along the line geometry.  [See this tutorial for generating points along a line](https://freegistutorial.com/how-to-create-regular-points-along-the-line-in-qgis/).

To duplicate the markers as points at the same interval go into the symbology of the line layer. See the marker placement interval to help you determine the intervals. [image]

Create the points with the [Points Along Geometry](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#points-along-geometry) tool.